# Remove all background space from HighCharts half dohnut chart

Tags: highcharts

How do I remove all the space around a HighCharts half dohnut chart?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle showing your current setting?

Comment: Hi @C. Hoj, Please reproduce the problem in some online code editor. You can start from: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c1bv3z4y/